# Ajax getElementById stop work when disconnect internet

Tags: ajax, file, getelementbyid

could someone help change this code? When it disconnects the internet and reconnects. When I disconnect the internet and reconnect the JS code no longer works. I would like the code to continue working even after reconnecting to the internet...  JS codes - refresh less often - if they miss the lack of internet, they work properly. the code stops working because it lacks the error value. I can't add it

I use `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>`

my page [www.consciousness.ct8.pl](http://consciousness.ct8.pl/) all files in page - [www.consciousness.ct8.pl/download/consciousness.rar](http://consciousness.ct8.pl/download/consciousness.rar)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var content = document.getElementById('playing');
  var call = function(){
    $.ajax({
      method:'POST',
      url:'radio/player/data/playing.php', 
      success:function(data){ 
        content.innerHTML = data; 
        setTimeout(call, 30000); // 30s.       
      }
    });
  }
  call();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe can't load jquery well.

Can you load jquery ?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I use file <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>  my page http://consciousness.ct8.pl/ all files in page - http://consciousness.ct8.pl/download/consciousness.rar

Comment: JS codes - refresh less often - if they miss the lack of internet, they work properly. the code stops working because it lacks the error value. I can't add it

Answer (score 0):

HELP? Information for user don't need when he is offilin. Enough that cod JS start again when he is back online. The current code JS not makeing do it.